# Can't access Ubuntu through USB after installation?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

I mounted the Ubuntu ISO image to an 8GB USB through LiLi USB Creator. I partitioned the hard drive and gave Ubuntu 100GB out of the 460GB available.
The problem is I have no idea how to access Ubuntu at all.

I've noticed the USB has the Ubuntu logo and it's renamed itself 'Install Ubuntu' which I definitely didn't do.

When I installed the first time, I reshuffled the BIOS. When the USB boots, I get this menu:

GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.3

Try Ubuntu without installing
Install Ubuntu
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Check disk for defects

I go through the Ubuntu installer fine, then I'm told I need to restart, which I do. Then I'm back to this menu like nothing happened.

I've 'installed' Ubuntu three times and nothing changed.

Is Ubuntu somewhere else? I have very little knowledge in live USBs (I've only done this with TAILS before). So how can I fix this ? And start using Ubuntu?

Thanks so much in advance ! And sorry if this seems obvious

Comment: Remove the USB before it boots, if you set your PC to boot USB first in bios, it will do this every time you restart it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, this looks like a Boot order issue in your BIOS.

The USB Stick you created was needed for installation, but once you installed Ubuntu you don't need to keep it plugged it. **So, first thing: remove USB stick.** :)

The next thing is to change your boot order to 'Ubuntu'. **You will need to do this in the BIOS.**

How to enter the BIOS can change from PC to PC. Sometimes it is hitting DEL when you first start up, sometimes it's F2. Your manufacturer will set that. Another option is to get Windows to go into the BIOS for you. 
**Press and hold SHIFT while clicking on RESTART** in Windows and follow the prompts (**Troubleshoot->UEFI Firmware Settings**)

Now you need to find the **Boot menu**, and select 'Ubuntu' as the default.

As an alternative to select a one-time boot option, a number of PCs have F12 as the key to hit when first starting the computer.

See if any of these work.

If you are dual-booting (which I am assuming you are, since you only gave 100GB to Ubuntu) then this should bring the **GRUB menu** to select either 'Ubuntu' or 'Windows'. Once you select 'Ubuntu, you will boot into your Ubuntu installation.

Comment: As it turns out the usb is literally only the installer. I didn't even think ubuntu would be in the BIOS >.< Thanks so much !!